# Why Amazon Forecast cannot train the predictor?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-forecast

While training my predictor I came across this error and I got stuck how to fix it.

I have two data-series, a "Target time-series data" with 9234 rows and a single "item_id" and a second one that is "Related time-series data" with the same number of rows as I only have a single id.

I'm setting de data with a window of 180 days, what is exactly the difference between the second and the first number that has appeared on the error, 9414 - 9234 = 180.

```
We were unable to train your predictor.
Please ensure there are no missing values for any items in the related time series, All items need data until 2020-03-15 00:00:00.0. For example, following items have missing data: item: brl only has 9234/9414 required datapoints starting 1994-06-07 00:00:00.0, please refer to documentation for additional details.
```

Once my data don't have missing data and it's on a daily basis why is it returning this error?
My data starts on 1994-06-07 and ends on 2019-09-17. Why should I have 9414 data points rather than 9234? 
Should I take out 180 days in my "Target time-series data"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The future values of the related time-series data must be known.

Example of a good related-time series: You know past and future days in which marketing has or will send email newsletters promoting the product you're forecasting. You can use this data as a related-time series.

Example of a bad related-time series: You notice that Google searches for your brand correlated with the sale of your product. As a result you want to use it as a related-time series. Since you don't know how many searches will occur in the future, so you can't use this as a related time series.

In you case, You have TARGET_TIME_SERIES data for 9414 days and you want to predict demand for the next 180 days. That means your RELATED_TIME_SERIES data should be 9594 days.

Edit: I have not tested this with amazon's forecasting product. I'm basing my answer on working with Facebook Prophet (which is one of the models amazon forcast uses). Please let me know if my solution worked.

Comment: You are correct! After reading your answer I dug in the documentation and I found exactly what you said! Thank you!

Comment: So I don't get how this exactly does any "future" predictions? Since we need to have related data up to the current date and target data lagged by n prediction days, we try to forecast the max we can forecast is up to the related data timestamp.

Comment: @LeggoMaEggo Correct. Predictions for n periods can be made with only the time series data. You can make the prediction better by feeding it related time series data, but you need to know the value of this data in the future.


If you don't know the future values for your related time series: Don't use it (do this 99% of the time), or make predictions for them.

Comment: There is a use case where you may want it, even if you don't know the future. My example is from retail, but I'm sure there are others. Historically, you know what the average sales price was each day (measure of discount). So you add that as a related series. Even if you don't know what the future holds, you could enter values at full price to get a "baseline" forecast of sales: how much will I sell if I don't offer any discount. Effectively, this helps you "remove" the effect of discounts, in your past data, and make your future forecast "more accurate".